# Postgres query to fetch rows matching xpath criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

My xmldata is,

```
<Transaction >
   <UUID>2017-03-17T08:00:00-086F0ADD43</UUID>
   <SequenceNumber Type="a">1</SequenceNumber>
   <SequenceNumber Type="b">1</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>
<Transaction >
   <UUID>2017-03-17T08:00:00-086F0ADD43</UUID>
   <SequenceNumber Type="a">2</SequenceNumber>
   <SequenceNumber Type="b">2</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>
```

My current query is:

```
select xmldata, cast ((xpath('/Transaction/SequenceNumber[@Type="b" and text()="1"]/text()', xmldata)) AS TEXT) from tbltransaction
```

This results in all rows,

```
    xmldata    | xpath
---------------+-----
 <Transaction> | {1}
 <Transaction> | {}
```

But I want the result set with exact value like below,

```
     xmldata    | xpath
---------------+-----
 <Transaction> | {1}
```

How to modify the above query to fetch this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filtering out using `WHERE`:

```
select s.r, xmldata 
from tbltransaction t
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT (xpath('/Transaction/SequenceNumber[@Type="b" and text()="1"]/text()',
            t.xmldata)::TEXT) AS r
     )s ON TRUE
WHERE s.r != '{}';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b627232cdb2a6891ab329e5d888f08b8)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [PostgreSQL 10 you can use XMLTABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING-XMLTABLE):

```
WITH data (xmldata) AS (VALUES('<Transaction >
   <UUID>2017-03-17T08:00:00-086F0ADD43</UUID>
   <SequenceNumber Type="a">1</SequenceNumber>
   <SequenceNumber Type="b">1</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>'::xml),('
<Transaction >
   <UUID>2017-03-17T08:00:00-086F0ADD43</UUID>
   <SequenceNumber Type="a">2</SequenceNumber>
   <SequenceNumber Type="b">2</SequenceNumber>
</Transaction>'::xml))

SELECT *
  FROM data
     , XMLTABLE('/Transaction/SequenceNumber[@Type="b" and text()="1"]/text()'
                PASSING xmldata
                COLUMNS xpath XML PATH '.'
               ) t;
```

Gives you:

```
                    xmldata                     | xpath
------------------------------------------------+-------
 <Transaction >                                +| 1
    <UUID>2017-03-17T08:00:00-086F0ADD43</UUID>+|
    <SequenceNumber Type="a">1</SequenceNumber>+|
    <SequenceNumber Type="b">1</SequenceNumber>+|
 </Transaction>                                 |
(1 row)
```